# Is "look who's talking" an appropriate response to "you are so beautiful"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Some time ago I came across an online exchange between two friends. It went something like this:

*A: Sweetie, you are so beautiful! (Commenting on her pic)*

*B:Look who's talking!*

Of course, B meant that A was more/ no less beautiful than A.

But I think we say **look who's talking** in reply to someone's critical remarks about someone else.

Can we use it in situations like this one? If not, what's an appropriate response in such cases?

Comment: Thanks, Xanne. If you could substantiate your answer with a few examples using the phrase in a positive sense, I would appreciate it. All I could find looking up a handful of online dictionaries was the use of the phrase in a negative sense.

Comment: You can search as well as I.

Comment: It could be taken as a playful, good-natured broadened usage. Quirky. Certainly informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that "look who's talking" is generally used in a negative context. Here are some alternatives.

- Right back at you.
- Takes one to know one.
- Game recognize game.

The last one's my favorite.